# How to send Upstream FCM messages from iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a Notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging from iOS,
I do not know what to define for let message.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/upstream

I refer to this URL, but it is written only as key-value.

```
let receiver: String = "\(senderID)@gcm.googleapis.com"
let message: [AnyHashable: Any] 
Messaging.messaging().sendMessage(message,
                             to: receiver,
                  withMessageID: UUID().uuidString,
                     timeToLive: 0)
```

What is the corresponding Key?

Are the four keys listed here?　Upstream XMPP messages.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#upstream

Comment: Hi. By *four keys*, do you mean the `message`, `to`, `withMessageID`, and `timeToLive`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation carefully, `message` is a dictionary.

> message is a dictionary of keys and values as strings. Any key-value
>   pair that is not a string is ignored.

So to define the `let message` you need to declare:

```
 let message: [String: String]
```

instead of

```
 let message: [AnyHashable: Any]
```

Also, to clarify this `message` dictionary will be custom and there is no particular key you need to define as you have asked.

For Example,

```
let message = ["Hello": "Name"]
```

The above `message` is valid.